# table already exists exception when migrate DB using Entity Framework Core and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and SQLite in UWP.  I tried to migrate  by calling DbContext.Database.Migrate() but I always get `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'table "Tags" already exists'.'`.

I'm sure that the table doesn't exist because I checked on bin/debug folder, there is no database file.  Even I check in wrong folder, there shouldn't have a problem doesn't it?
I've deleted Migrations folder many times but I don't think this is the cause of this exception.

This is DbContext code.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WordMeaning> WordMeanings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WordTag> WordTags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=Vocabulary.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // PK declaration
        modelBuilder.Entity<Word>()
            .HasKey(w => w.Text);
        modelBuilder.Entity<WordMeaning>()
            .HasKey(wm => new { wm.WordText, wm.WordClass });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
            .HasKey(t => t.Name);
        modelBuilder.Entity<WordTag>()
            .HasKey(wt => new { wt.WordText, wt.TagName });

        // relation declaration
        modelBuilder.Entity<Word>()
            .HasMany(w => w.WordMeanings)
            .WithOne(wm => wm.Word)
            .HasForeignKey(wm => wm.WordText)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WordTag>()
            .HasOne(wt => wt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.WordTag)
            .HasForeignKey(wt => wt.TagName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<WordTag>()
            .HasOne(wt => wt.Word)
            .WithMany(w => w.WordTag)
            .HasForeignKey(wt => wt.WordText);
    }
}
```

and all of models code.

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<WordTag> WordTag { get; set; }
}
public class Word
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public WordClass WordClasses { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public List<WordMeaning> WordMeanings { get; set; }
    public List<WordTag> WordTag { get; set; }
}
public class WordMeaning
{
    public string WordText { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
    public string Example { get; set; }
    public WordClass WordClass { get; set; }
    public Word Word { get; set; }
}
public class WordTag
{
    public Word Word { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public string WordText { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your user folder? Like `C:\user\username` on W10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gert Arnold said,  Your SQLite database file (Vocabulary.db) should be created on the [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) by default. You should be able to find the database with `Tag` table is already created on `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{your app package name}\LocalState)`. The package name you can find by `Package.appxmanifest->Packing->Package name` on your project. More details about the file access on uwp app please reference [Files, folders, and libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/).

And more details about entity framework with uwp please reference [UWP - New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started).

Comment: Thank you, now I can delete *.db and Migrate() didn't throws exception anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Do not use both `EnsureCreated` and `Migrate`, Only **Migrate** enough to create and migrate the DB

```
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    //db.Database.EnsureCreated(); Don't use
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```